# How to pass a plain(not annotated api parameter) object with MockMvc

Tags: java, integration-testing, mockmvc

i am trying to pass a regular object to an api, via the MockMvc library.
Here is the example (Partiucalarly the `FilterProperties properties` object):

API:

```
@GetMapping("/test-api")
    public PageResponse<SomeDto> getAllObjects(
            FilterProperties properties,
            @RequestParam(value = "searchPhrase", defaultValue = "") String searchPhrase,
            @RequestParam(value = "actionType") ActionType actionType) {
        System.out.println(searchPhrase);
        return null;
    }
```

I managed to successfully pass the @RequestParams with `.param("searchPhrase", "SomePhrase")`, however i cannot seem to find a way to pass the FilterProperties object, since its just a plain object and is not annotated as param, request body or some sort of attribute.

TEST:

```
final MvcResult mvcResult = restServiceMockMvc
                .perform(get(CONTROLLER_BASE_PATH + "/test-api")
                        .param("searchPhrase", "SomePhrase")
                        .param("actionType", String.valueOf(ActionType.EDIT))
                        .requestAttr("properties", filterProperties)
                        .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn();
```

I tried with requestAttr, flashAttr, sessionAttr and it does not break the call, however the api receives an empty object for filterProperties.

I appreciate any insights!

Comment: Please, remove this tag from your list: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/spring-integration/info. It is not relevant to the topic and misleading. Thanks. And yes: looks like Spring Boot is also out of scope in your question.

Answer (score 0):

`FilterProperties` will be treated as there are `@ModelAttribute` annotated on it (mentioned by the rules in this [table](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments)).

And `@ModelAttribute` will enable data binding which will try to bind the value from query parameters , or field name of the form data or others (see [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-initbinder) for more details) to `FilterProperties` .

So that means assuming `FilterProperties` has the following fields :

```java
public class FilterProperties {
        
        private String prop1;
        private String prop2;
}
```

Then you can configure the `MockMvc` as

```java
mockMvc.perform(get(CONTROLLER_BASE_PATH + "/test-api")
                        .param("searchPhrase", "SomePhrase")
                        .param("actionType", String.valueOf(ActionType.EDIT))
                        .param("prop1", "prop1-value")
                        .param("prop2", "prop2-value"))
```

in order to pass the following values to the fields of the  `FilterProperties` :

```
prop1 = prop1-value
prop2 = prop2-value
```

Answer (score 0):

whenever you pass an object to an api, it has to be part of the api signature in one way or another; i guess here you want to pass a body for the GET api(which is highly discouraged),since GET calls are idempotent by nature.

if though if its for testing try passing it as a requestbody and then mock it